# Ember.js: each roundtrip to api adds new portion of the same values

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Continue playing with Ember.js

I'm just getting values from api and trying to display it.
I successfully got data, but when I load route again (click on link) data appended to list instead of replacing. How many times I clicked - each time full list appended to the end.

The code is big, don't realize what part to show actually.

Maybe the reason is in key mapping? i make it like this

```
App.Adapter.map('Semantic', {
    primaryKey: 'key'
});
```

EDIT: JsFiddle link - http://jsfiddle.net/bug0r/94h3a/31/

Click on about and then again on Home.

Comment: You should post the code for the route / controller that is displaying the data. Also highlight where you are fetching the data from the API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an issue with your DataStore / RESTAdapter model key setup.

Try the following :

```
DS.RESTAdapter.reopen({
  url: 'http://bug0r.apiary.io/api'
});

App.Adapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  serializer: DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
    primaryKey: function (type){
      return 'key';
   }
  })
});

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    revision: 12,
    adapter: App.Adapter
});
```

This gives the DataStore / RESTAdapter vital information regarding the primary key of your records. Without it it has no way of knowing what records it has already available internally and what it is receiving from the REST API (so it keeps on appending the data coming from the REST API).

See forked fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/ddewaele/eJCsQ/

Comment: Yes, this works.
If I want to make it just for special type, I can use switch to filter parameter 'type' at primaryKey member. right?

Comment: @bug0r : I think the preferred way is to use the DS.RESTAdapter.configure to switch between different types.

Comment: How to call it for this purpose?